# How can I integrate Twitter Bootstrap CSS and Javascript into a vanilla VueJS project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, vue.js

```
vue init webpack helloworld
npm run dev
```

Awesome, I have a Vue project.

How can I integrate Twitter Bootstrap (latest) in my project? CSS and Javascript.

I tried to install it using NPM and referencing it in `index.html`.

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Then:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot GET /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1):

You can find detailed instructions here: https://www.namekdev.net/2016/08/load-boostrap-4-alpha-into-vue-js-project/

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it, using vue-strap, uncompiled bootstrap 3 Sass: https://github.com/pmsaue0/vuejs-bootstrap3